# String comparison on elements in large arrays (> 11 mill)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, gpu, string-comparison

Trying to compare different environments on id's (string). The largest array is 11,5 mill rows.

What I want to do is to combine all id's from the different arrays and then tell what environment each id is in

What I'm trying to create:

| id (all ids of all arrays(df) | prod | preprod | test | dev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| first string | True | True | True | False |
| second string | False | True | False | True |
| 21gdfwg23fge | True | True | False | False |
| adf23 dfg a2-5 | True | False | True | True |

Example 1

```
%%time
dfs = [prod,preprod,test,dev]
arrs = [np.array(df).flatten() for df in dfs]
all_ids = np.unique([item for sublist in arrs for item in sublist])
n_ids = len(all_ids)
n_arrs = len(arrs)
result = np.zeros((n_ids, n_arrs))
for i in range(n_arrs):
    result[:, i] = [1 if all_ids[j] in arrs[i] else 0 for j in range(n_ids)]
result_df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['dev', 'test', 'preprod', 'prod'], index = all_ids)
print(result_df)
```

Example 2: (easier to read)

```
final = pd.concat([prod, preprod, dev, test]).drop_duplicates()
final = final.dropna()

all = final

prod_num = prod.to_numpy()
preprod_num = prod.to_numpy()
dev_num = dev.to_numpy()
test_num = test.to_numpy()

prod_isin = np.isin(all,prod_num)
preprod_isin = np.isin(all,preprod_num)
dev_isin = np.isin(all, dev_num)
test_isin = np.isin(all, test_num)

final["prod"] = prod_isin
final["preprod"] = preprod_isin
final["dev"] = dev_isin
final["test"] = test_isin
print(final)
```

The code works but it's all **too slow**.

I've also tried GPU (without getting it to work (got an Nvidia 1080 TI)). Think what I should do is to sort the "main" list and then use some kind of sorthing algorithm to make the match.

All help will be appriciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pandas concatenation with index matching, it's very fast.

```
prod = "aa|b|c|d|e".split('|')
preprod = "c|d|e".split('|')
test = "b|d|e|f".split('|')
dev = "aa|e|g".split('|')

df = pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame({'prod': 1}, index=np.unique(prod)),
    pd.DataFrame({'preprod': 1}, index=np.unique(preprod)),
    pd.DataFrame({'test': 1}, index=np.unique(test)),
    pd.DataFrame({'dev': 1}, index=np.unique(dev))
], axis=1, sort=False).fillna(0).reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'id'})
print(df)

>>> 
   id  prod  preprod  test  dev
0  aa   1.0      0.0   0.0  1.0
1   b   1.0      0.0   1.0  0.0
2   c   1.0      1.0   0.0  0.0
3   d   1.0      1.0   1.0  0.0
4   e   1.0      1.0   1.0  1.0
5   f   0.0      0.0   1.0  0.0
6   g   0.0      0.0   0.0  1.0
```

and for speed;

```py
prod = np.random.randint(10000000, size=10000000).astype(str)
preprod = np.random.randint(10000000, size=1000000).astype(str)
test = np.random.randint(10000000, size=1000000).astype(str)
dev = np.random.randint(10000000, size=100000).astype(str)


%%time
df = pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame({'prod': 1}, index=np.unique(prod)),
    pd.DataFrame({'preprod': 1}, index=np.unique(preprod)),
    pd.DataFrame({'test': 1}, index=np.unique(test)),
    pd.DataFrame({'dev': 1}, index=np.unique(dev))
], axis=1, sort=False).fillna(0).reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'id'})

>>> Wall time: 32.3 s
```

on my humble laptop.

Comment: You are awesome! After 17 hours running on a MacBook pro i7 32gb ram I had to stop. When doing it your way the compute took more like 30 seconds :)